# manipulate html with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have something like this:

```
<div id='cb1'>
<input name='c1' value='12'>
<input name='c1' value='32'>
   ...
<input name='c1' value='32'>
</div>

<div id='z1'>
</div>
```

and I need to 
copy all the inputs from `#cb1` to `#z1` and rename them to `x1`, so I would get this:

```
<div id='z1'>
<input name='x1' value='12'>
<input name='x1' value='32'>
   ...
<input name='x1' value='32'>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you want to name all your inputs the same?!

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet it's an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#cb1').find('input').clone().attr('name', 'x1').appendTo('#z1');
```

Use `.clone(true)` if you have attached data and events that need to be copied too.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#cb1").children().attr("name", "x1").appendTo($("#z1"));
```

or

```
$("#cb1").children().clone(true).attr("name", "x1").appendTo($("#z1"));
```

Here we take the children (the inputs) from `#cb1` and we optionally clone them depending on whether you want to *move* them from `#cb1`  to `#z1` or whether you want to duplicate them in `#z1`

Then we set the attr of `name` to `x1` for all of them and then we appendTo the `#z1` container.

Argueably you want to use [`.find("input")`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) as @Box9 mentioned depending on whether it has any other children. If `#cb1` only has inputs then `.children` is faster otherwise we can take the `input` elements only. You can also use `.children("input")`

Also `.find` looks for nested inputs and `.children` only looks down one layer

[`.children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), [`.appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), [`.clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score -1):

$("#cb1").html("put here the html");

Comment: -1 for not knowing nor searching enough about jQuery capabilities for this kind of problem, and giving a rather bad solution. Box9 and Raynos has proven that much better solutions are available.